# Let $H,K\leq G$ such that $G=HK$. Show that there exist $P\in Syl_p(H)$ and $Q\in Syl_p(K)$ such that $PQ\in Syl_p(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Question: Let $G$ be a finite group with subgroups $H$ and $K$ such that $G=HK$.  Show that there exist $P\in Syl_p(H)$ and $Q\in Syl_p(K)$ such that $PQ\in Syl_p(G)$.

My thoughts: Since $G=HK$, we know that $|G|=|HK|=|H||K|/|H\cap K|$.  I feel like it would be nice if $|H\cap K|=1$ and $|H|=p$ and $|K|=q$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes, because then we could use Sylow's third theorem, but we can't say that.  I suppose the existence of $P\in Syl_p(H)$ and $Q\in Syl_p(K)$ is ``obvious", but I feel like I am missing something easy that we can say about $|P|$ and $|Q|$ that will get us to the solution.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: This question is answered here: [Existence of $A \in \operatorname{Syl}_p(H)$ and $B \in \operatorname{Syl}_p(K)$ such that $AB \in \operatorname{Syl}_p(G)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3650522/existence-of-a-in-operatornamesyl-ph-and-b-in-operatornamesyl-pk), but I was wondering if there were any alternative methods without considering such intersections (though, I couldn't think of any because of the pesky $H\cap K$ being involved)

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis I saw that answer, but I was wondering if there were any alternative methods... I will edit the question with that info included..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: See the linked duplicate, this proof was wrong.

Comment: That's basically the answer given in the linked question. OP is specifically asking for a different approach.

Comment: @Giorgos Giapitzakis: at the time I started typing the answer, the edit wasn't there.

Comment: It's true. OP did not clarify this until it got flagged as a duplicate. Besides, I don't think there is another proof avoiding a similar argument. +1

Comment: .Yeah, I agree.

Comment: Yes, my mistake for not mentioning that when I first typed the question.  Thank you everyone for the help!!

Comment: I don't believe the "fact": $|hTh^{-1} \cap H| = |T \cap H|$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Do you have a counterexample in mind?  In the solution given by Nicky Hester on the linked problem, it seemed like it was just that approach, but, certainly, that "fact" (at least to me) isn't obvious and would require some work to show.

Comment: It true only when we already have $T \cap H \in {\rm Syl}_p(H)$, because $|hTh^{-1} \cap H| = |T \cap H|$ for all $h \in H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt is right, I don’t know what I was thinking, I misapplied Sylow II. See the linked answer for the right approach.

Answer (score -2):

I'm sorry, I guess this is false (actually your first deduction about cardinality of $G$ isn't correct, the following counterexample works for this point too).
Take, for example, $G = S_3$, $H=\langle(12)\rangle$, $K=\langle(13)\rangle$. Then you have $Syl_2(H)=\{H\}$ and $Syl_2(K)=\{K\}$, so the only possible choice of such sylows is given by $H$ and $K$, respectively, but $HK=S_3\notin Syl_2(S_3)$.

Comment: Note that $(13)(12) \not \in HK$ so this isn't a counterexample.

Comment: $|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|} \leq |H||K| = 4$ so how is $S_3 = HK$?

Comment: If by writing $HK$ you mean only the ordered products from elements of $H$ and $K$ respectively (and not the generated subgroup by the two subgroups) then sorry, I was wrong.
But if this is the case I guess we can assume the fact that $G$ is the semi-direct product of $H$ and $K$

Comment: I have never seen the notation $HK$ used in the context of semi-direct products though.